# How can Apex impact the ability to make declarative changes?

Tags: apex, certification, platform-developer-1

I'm looking at the study guide for the Platform Developer 1 certification.

[Here's a link to the study guide.](http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformDeveloperI.pdf?v=8)

Under the **Logic and Process Automation** section one of the headings is:

> Describe how Apex impacts the ability to make declarative changes.

I'm only familiar with API names changing that could affect Apex code that isn't using dynamic describes. Is there any other way Apex could impact declarative changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite broad (and possibly off topic), but here are some of the most common cases:

**Apex Blocks Declarative Changes**

- Failing Unit Tests in Production will block deployments.
- Any `API Name` referenced in code (Object, Field, etc.) cannot be changed.

  - The referenced field or object cannot be deleted either, nor have it's type changed.
  - It doesn't count if it's a String reference.
- Triggers can interact poorly with Rollup Summary Fields, Formulas, Process Builder, etc.

  - It is rare for this issue to crop up, but I have seen it happen. Sometimes the programmatic or declarative side just needs more careful design.
  - Then again, this situation does not affect your ability to *make* the declarative change, it just turns it into a *breaking* change.

**Apex Enables Declarative Changes**

- You might argue that when developers incorporate Custom Settings or configuration objects into their code, that makes an aspect of their functionality declarative.
- Using the `Metadata API`, some other programmatic functionality can be made declarative to an extent.

Comment: I can't find any good documentation on how Apex can impact the declarative side. I think the question itself is a bit vague. Any insights from the community could prove useful, as there's not much info that I can find about the subject on Google. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: The first two are the most obvious that I can think of.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Would execution order be noteworthy do you think? Potentially a workflow rule could overwrite data from a Trigger. Granted the phrasing implies this would be the other way round.

Comment: Right, it's not asking about how declarative functionality affects `Apex`, which would be much more broad indeed. @Poet

Comment: @AdrianLarson Do you mind expanding a bit or pointing me to some examples on your point about the `Metadata API` making some programmatic functionality declarative ?

Comment: I haven't really ever used it myself, more of a hypothetical application. You could perhaps parse a `Page Layout` for use in a custom `Visualforce Page`, for example.